# Grep a list of SQL table names within the file contents of a directory matching a table name format

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script that would be able to grep table names from across files (within a directory) that partially match a string.

For my case, I'd like to return all table references following a certain convention (case insensitive):

- tblpl
- tbljoin
- tbldim

This would ideally return a list like this:

```
product.dbo.tblplColors
product..tblplMonograms
solr.dbo.tbljoinSkuCategory
```

Matching one table name format at a time would also be alright if that helped reduce some of the complexity. To clarify, this would return just the table names- not the file name/all of the file contents. It's safe to say the end of the table name would be delimited by a space since it's SQL.

Where I've started:

```
 grep -rio 'tblpl*[^ ]' d:/sqldirectoryhere > c:/Users/foo/Desktop/tables.txt
```

Any help/pointers are appreciated here- thanks!

**Edit:** Both of these answers nailed my use case. I ended up adding the extended regex (so huge thanks for that recommendation) but I have to give credit to the person who wrote the bulk of it. Thanks all!

My extended use case ended up being a way to return this list of tables and then script it to a query-friendly format so I could throw these into a WHERE IN clause. In case anyone ever needs it:

```
grep -rioE --no-filename '[a-zA-Z_.]+\.tbl(pl|join|dim)[a-zA-Z_]+' {DIRECTORY_HERE} | sed -n 's/.*/\x27&\x27/; $! s/$/,/; 1 h; 1 ! H; $ { x; s/\n/ /g; p; }'
```

Returns formatted as: 'db.tblplColorSwatches', 'db.tbljoinCustomerSegment'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finds any mixed sequence of letters and periods followed by `.tblpl` or `.tbljoin` or `.tbldim` followed by one or more letters (see [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/oQ5pI9/5))

try this regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z.]+\.tbl(pl|join|dim)[a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: Can you please expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Comment: it finds any mixed sequence of letters and periods followed by .tblpl or .tbljoin or .tbldim followed by one or more letters (see regex101 link)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `-E` flag to use extended regular expression:

```
grep -rioE '[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\.tbl(pl|join|dim)[a-z]*' d:/sqldirectoryhere
```